# How to get title data from catalog_product_bundle_option_value table by using option_id

Tags: magento

I am using the code shown below to get data from `catalog_product_bundle_option_value` table.

```
$selectOptionID = "SELECT title FROM " . $prefix . "catalog_product_bundle_option_value WHERE option_id = " . $eachOption->getData('option_id') . "";
```

Comment: Can anyone please help me? how to get data from catalog_product_bundle_option_value table by using magento module.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
   $bind = array(
                'prefix'    => "".$prefix."catalog_product_bundle_option_value",
                'option_Id'   => $eachOption->getData('option_id'),
            );

//Open Database Conenction
$write = Mage::getSingleton("core/resource")->getConnection("core_write");

$query("SELECT title FROM :prefix Where option_id = :option_Id");

 $selectOptionID = $write->query($query, $bind);
```

Above untested. if it dont work try this.

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
        $selectOptionID = $connection->fetchAll("SELECT title FROM ".$prefix."catalog_product_bundle_option_value" Where option_id = ".$eachOption->getData('option_id'));
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code, but I was not expecting this code, I want how i can get data from that table by using magento module. My coding is working fine, but i don't thing its secure. so can you please help me

Comment: i dont understand what you want you are trying to do? explain it a bit more lol

Comment: Now the data is fetching by using the database connection like -  $write = Mage::getSingleton("core/resource")->getConnection("core_write"); I want everything will be fetch by using magento module like Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($optionId);